# Having trouble passing argument through function

Tags: c++

Having trouble with the function call for monthlyAverage() function because I do not know what to pass through in order for it to work.

```c++
// Zachary Fernandez
// Term Project Part II
// TP21_rainfall_statisitcs.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void userInput(double rainfall[]);
double totalRainfall(double rainfall[]);
double monthlyAverage(double sum);

int main()
{
    double rainfall[12];

    cout << "Please enter the rainfall of each month of the year\n";
    cout << "seperated by a space.\n";

    userInput(rainfall);

    totalRainfall(rainfall);

    monthlyAverage();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void userInput(double rainfall[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cin >> rainfall[i];
    }
}

double totalRainfall(double rainfall[])
{
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        sum += rainfall[i];
    }

    cout << "The total amount of rainfall for the year is: ";
    cout << sum;
    cout << endl;

    return sum;
}
```

Having trouble with this function because the function call is not allowing me to pass anything through. I also do not know what to pass through in order for it to work.

```
double monthlyAverage(double sum)
{
    double average;

    average = (sum / 12);

    cout << "The average monthly rain fall is: ";
    cout << average;
    cout << endl;

    return average;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need something like this:

```
int main()
{
    double rainfall[12];

    cout << "Please enter the rainfall of each month of the year\n";
    cout << "seperated by a space.\n";

    userInput(rainfall);

    double total = totalRainfall(rainfall);

    double avg = monthlyAverage(total);

    cout << "Monthly Average:" << avg << endl;    

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function takes one double Argument

```
 double monthlyAverage(double sum);
```

So you must pass a double value in order to work.Like

```
monthlyAverage(100.5);
```

In your case it is look like this

```
monthlyAverage(totalRainfall(rainfall));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you declared it to take in a double, so any double value will work. I am assuming sum means total rainfall, so you can either store the value of the totalRainfall() function in a variable, then pass the variable, or do something like

```
int average = monthlyAverage(totalRainfall(rainfall));
```

This will use the value returned by the totalRainfall function and pass it into monthlyAverage, then store the result into int average.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `totalRainfall` method prototype is - `double totalRainfall(double rainfall[])`, it means the function is returning a `double` value which you can pass to `monthlyAverage` function.

```
double total = totalRainfall(rainfall);
double avg = monthlyAverage(total);
```

You can store the return value in a variable (`avg` in the example) as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your context, this exercise (?) seem to suggest that you write

```
monthlyAverage(totalRainfall(rainfall));
```

Why? you see that `totalRainfall` returns a `double`, and it passes to `monthlyAverage` to output the average.

By the way, your `system("pause");` is not very portable. 
[Say, Apple version is different](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2130719?tstart=0).

Comment: Wow, 5 answers in 3 minutes. I was slow.